# setContentView() Crashes when used with GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-activity

I have been trying to make my first android app. I am stuck with this strange problem. There are lot of people who had faced same problem (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087266/setcontentview-crashes-android-application-in-listview), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739215/setcontentview-crashes-android-emulator), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598896/setcontentview-says-source-not-found) and lots of other places) in past but none of the solutions seems to work for me.

My problem is if I set layout file like `setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity)` application crashes on this function but if I directly set `GLSurfaceView` as content view application works just fine. I want to have a `ListView` and `GLSurfaceView` on same screen thats why I am trying to add it in XML.

Here is my layout file

> ```
> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical">
>
> <com.example.camerafilters.CameraGLSurfaceView 
>   android:id="@+id/CameraGLSurfaceView"
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
>
> <!-- <ListView
> android:id="@+id/ShaderList"
> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
>   -->                                 
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Here is relevant portion from main activity. Note that `CameraGLSurfaceView` is an inner class.

```
public class CameraMainActivity extends Activity implements
SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener 
{
private CameraGLSurfaceView _cameraGLView;

/**
 * Captures frames from an image stream as an OpenGL ES texture. The image stream may come from either camera preview or video decode.
 *  A SurfaceTexture may be used in place of a SurfaceHolder when specifying the output destination of a Camera or MediaPlayer object
 */
private SurfaceTexture _surface;

CameraGLRenderer _renderer;

private Camera _camera;

private ListView _shaderListView;

class CameraGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView 
{
    CameraGLRenderer renderer;
    public CameraGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        //  Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        renderer = new CameraGLRenderer((CameraMainActivity)context);
        setRenderer(renderer);

        //  Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

    public CameraGLRenderer getRenderer()
    {
        return renderer;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    _cameraGLView = new CameraGLSurfaceView(this, null);
    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity. 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _cameraGLView = (CameraGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraGLSurfaceView);
    _renderer = _cameraGLView.getRenderer();

}
```

Any pointers where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at the exception stacktrace in logcat to find the exact problem.

Then, guessing the problem is that the view specified in your XML cannot be instantiated: your inner class needs to be `public static` and you need to refer to it correctly in XML, like

```
com.example.camerafilters.CameraMainActivity$CameraGLSurfaceView
```

though it's cleaner to have it as a separate class instead of an inner class.

Comment: yeah thats the first thing we should do. But i can't conclude anything from stacktrace or logcat. this was the problem indeed. I just moved that inner class outside and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why u calling it before onCreate ? You don't need to call it since you defined it in your xml layout.
You dont need to call it all. Just delete the line before setContentView.

Comment: in some posts i found that they need to create that GLSurface before setting layout XML. Thats why i added it there. It crashes without that also.

Comment: Then check if u have typed the package name in ur xml file correct. And delete that line as it doesn't do anything. Since u define it in ur xml.

Comment: Hmm i deleted. Its corect @laato's answer solved it for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `GLSurfaceView.setRenderer()` in your `Activity.onCreate()`